# VBA - How to set printarea for multiple pages in one sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I am using this code

```
Sub print_area()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

With ws.PageSetup

.PrintTitleColumns = "$A:$E"
.PrintArea = ws.Range("A128").Value
.CenterHorizontally = True

End With

Next
End Sub
```

`Range("A128").Value` has the value as this: $F$1:$AF$125,$AG$1:$BE$125,$BF$1:$CD$125,$CE$1:$DA$125,$DB$1:$DX$125

print areas are not set properly (the areas are close to set range but not as desired), what other parameters do I have to set to make it work right?

Red arrow indicates where the print area should be

[image]

Comment: You might want to change `Range("A128").Value` to `ws.Range("A128").Value`, since you're looping through worksheets.

Comment: Made that change, still not working :/. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule, Excel automatically sets page breaks for printing based on paper size, scale, specified number of sheets in width and height, page orientation, and other parameters. You can use [VPageBreak object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.vpagebreak) and [HPageBreak object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hpagebreak) in combination with a number of `.PageSetup` properties to manually fit page breaks. Note that you cannot set page breaks with the `.PrintArea` property (see below in the code for why). In the following code I set page breaks after the cells "AF1", "BE1", "CD1", "DA1", "DX1":

```
Sub print_area()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.PageSetup
            .PrintTitleColumns = "$A:$E"
            .PrintArea = "$F$1:$AF$125,$AG$1:$BE$125,$BF$1:$CD$125,$CE$1:$DA$125,$DB$1:$DX$125" ' there will be one area between the upper left and lower right cells
            Debug.Print .PrintArea  ' check the final .PrintArea; prints $F$1:$DX$125
            .Zoom = False
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .FitToPagesWide = False 'it's Auto
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
            .CenterHorizontally = True
            ws.ResetAllPageBreaks
            breaks = Array("AF1", "BE1", "CD1", "DA1", "DX1")   'zero-based array
            For i = 1 To UBound(breaks)
                ws.VPageBreaks.Add Before:=ws.Range(breaks(i - 1)).Offset(, 1)
            Next
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

> **Please note** that in response to your pagination actions, Excel can
> (and usually does) change the pagination itself

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code, It did not work. Would you know another path to solve this issue?

Comment: After a long time, I finally understood your code. Thanks